# Move recently viewed product or completely remove it

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, products, recently-viewed

Magento has a great feature to show recently viewed product, but now I need to move this element (recently viewed product)  to exactly on the top of footer.

[image]

I have no clue about how to show/hide or move this recently viewed product to the another area on the page?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to display in home page?

Comment: yes in Home page but not on the top of home content, I want to place it on the bottom of content (on the top of Footer). can you help me to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see recently viewed products widgets in `Admin panel->Content->Widgets` you can remove completely from here.

To display recently viewed products in bottom of the page, create CMS static block(`Admin panel->Content->Blocks`) and click on Insert widget option and select widget type as recently viewed products widget and save the block.

After that go to `Admin panel->Content->Widgets`, create widget with below requirements.
[image: Widget page]

In widget options tab you can select the created recenlty viewed CMS block.

Comment: unfortunately, i cannot found "recently viewed CMS block"  on the select block option list ?

Comment: Did you create CMS static block with recently view widget?

Comment: yeah, I just realized that, after I removed that now it disappear

Comment: okie........:-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<move element=“your-block-name” destination="main.content" after="-"/>
```

Comment: In file & section should the  above code be added?